# From which location does Python access the installed packages?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I have standalone Python alongwith Anaconda3 Python installed on my PC.
When I run pip list -v , I get the list from the image:

1. Few packages are installed with pip, few with conda
2. Packages are installed at different locations.

When I run python, the interdependent packages try to access one another from different locations.
Few packages do not work as expected because of the location conflict
What is the best way to go forward?
Uninstall one of the python ?

[image]

Comment: Just let it be If you don't encounter any problems.

Comment: have you added any paths to PATH or PYTHONPATH yourself?

Comment: @FlyingTeller : i have added this to PATH  /anaconda3/lib